How to run Gigapose for 2D RGB image object pose estimation with STL mesh model?
I'm trying to use the Gigapose library (https://github.com/nv-nguyen/gigapose) for pose estimation of an object on a 2D RGB image using an STL mesh model. I've set up the environment, but I'm stuck on how to actually run the pose estimation.
Steps I've taken:
Installed Python 3.9.6
Installed requirements from the .yaml file and adjusted them for pip3 instead of conda:
torchvision
omegaconf
torchmetrics==0.10.3
fvcore
iopath
xformers==0.0.18
opencv-python
pycocotools
matplotlib
onnxruntime
onnx
scipy
ffmpeg
hydra-colorlog
hydra-core
gdown
pytorch-lightning==1.8.1
pandas
ruamel.yaml
pyrender
wandb
distinctipy
blenderproc

What I'm trying to do:

Perform pose estimation on my 2D RGB image.
Use my .STL mesh model for the estimation.

Problems I am facing:

I can't find clear documentation on how to set up and run the code.
Repo itself is massive and there is a lot of code which I am not able to comprehend.
I'm unsure how to input my 2D RGB image and .STL mesh model into the Gigapose pipeline and get the result (rvec and tvec).


problem 1: file an issue, request clarified documentation. -- problem 2: that's ok, nobody's supposed to read all that. they provide it for you to run, and hopefully it just runs, if the requirements are installed. -- problem 3: same as 1, request better docs.

broadly, that paper and repo looks like you're supposed to take your 3D geometry and render many views of it, and that goes into their program.

@ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the suggestions and input. I’ll see what I can do
